# Copying values of a numpy array with floats

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
y = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3], [0.4,0.5,0.743], [0.834,0.96,0.1]])
```

I was trying to copy some columns in `y` into X using the following:

```
X[:, [0,1]] = y[:, [0,1]]
```

However after I print `X` I get:

```
In[20]: X
Out[20]: 
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 9]])
```

As you can see, as if the floats are rounded. I want the floats as is without rounding, how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dtype of x is `int` as it has all integer values,

so just change the dtype while creating x as below:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], dtype=float)
y = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3], [0.4,0.5,0.743], [0.834,0.96,0.1]])

x[:, [0,1]] = y[:, [0,1]]

print(x)
```

Output:

```
[[0.1   0.2   3.   ]
 [0.4   0.5   6.   ]
 [0.834 0.96  9.   ]]
```

**Edit**

Or if you dont create `x` manually then as  @Arda Keskiner suggested in comments use:

```
x = x.astype(float)
x[:, [0,1]] = y[:, [0,1]]
```

Comment: Correct answer. What you can also do is define X and then change it's type to float by using `.astype(float) `.

```X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]).astype(float)```

Comment: That's useful when you are getting value from some source and don't have control over it. But if you are creating array then using `dtype` parameter is effcient as there is overhead for calling a methd `astype`.